# Django send email with attachement

Tags: python, django, django-email

I tried to send some files in mail using Django `EmailMessage` class

The files attachment that I want to send are in DB, provided by each user during registration to my site.

I'have tried this but it does not work

myapp/views.py:

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage

def contactUber(request,id):
    user = User.objects.get(id=id)
    msg = EmailMessage(
        'Hello', #subject
        'Body goes here', #content
        'vitalysweb@gmail.com', #from
        ['uber@uber.com'] #to
        )
    msg.attach_file(user.profile.id_card.url) #the file that i want to attach
    msg.send()
    messages.success(request, "Email envoyé avec succes") #success msg
    return redirect(user_detail, id=str(id))
```

myapp/models:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    birth_date = models.DateField(('Date de naissance'), null=True, blank=True)
    #DOCUMENTS TO UPLOAD
    id_card = models.FileField(('Carte Nationale d\'Identité'), upload_to='documents/CNI')
    drive_licence = models.FileField(('Permis de conduire'), upload_to='documents/RIB')
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(('Ajouté le'), auto_now=True)
    docs_are_checked = models.BooleanField(('Documents validés'), default=False)
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\venvs\env1\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 41, in inner
response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\venvs\env1\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 187, in _get_response
response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\venvs\env1\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 185, in _get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\djangoprojects\mysite\mysite\core\views.py", line 272, in contactUber
msg.attach_file(user.profile.id_card.url) #the file that i want to attach
  File "C:\venvs\env1\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\message.py", line 394, in attach_file
with open(path, 'rb') as file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/media/documents/CNI/1847635-2524541_FZLHlIr.jpg'
[16/Aug/2017 12:10:27] "GET /core/send_mail_uber/16/ HTTP/1.1" 500 73307
```

My question is : How to fix this

Comment: and what is your question? Is it how to fix this? Why is it happening? Or what? please be clear when posting on SO.

Comment: @N.Ivanov   edit done

Answer (score 0):

Since the file is stored in your DB, it will probably not be saved `/media/documents/CNI/1847635-2524541_FZLHlIr.jpg` at this location. So what you have to do is specify the filename, data, mimetype using the `attach()` method. Here is an example of how it should work:

```
msg.attach(user.profile.id_card.name, user.profile.id_card.read(), user.profile.id_card.content_type)
```

You can read more at [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/email/). Look for `attach()`, and know that it is different from `attach_file()`

**EDIT 1**

Since you mentioned in the comments that `id_card` throws an error, I am assuming you are not fetching the correct model. From what I can see I am unsure if you are doing it correctly. You should fetch the `Profile` model instance in the following way:

```
someVar = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user) # assuming the current user is the one that you would like to be
```

and then in order to attach the file use:

```
msg.attach(someVar.id_card.name, someVar.id_card.read(), 'image/png') # assuming you will be attaching png's only
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: id_card is not defined (NameError)

Comment: @VITALYSWEB I have updated my answer, should be `user.profile.id_card` if that doesn't work then you are probably not fetching the correct model.

Comment: @VITALYSWEB I have updated my answer look under **EDIT 1**. Hope this helps!

Comment: Now i'm having this error :

AttributeError at /core/send_mail_uber/8/

'FieldFile' object has no attribute 'content_type'

Sorry to be so annoying, I'm a beginner in django

Comment: @VITALYSWEB If you will be sending only images you can hardcode it like so `'image/png'`, and that should be the fastest workaround. I would suggest you to go over some django tutorials [Tango with Django](https://leanpub.com/tangowithdjango19/) is a free one, and will help you understand django more. Also may I ask you if this solved your problem, to upvote and mark the answer as accepted so that future visitors can solve their issue faster? Thanks!

Comment: thanx for the suggestion, for my i case i have to send both imageFiles and PDF.
i'll try to get more informations about django Contentypes and look for a solution after

Comment: a tip to get your emails up and running, you can split the filename and check the file extension (pdf, jpg, png) and have a dictionary like `myDict = {"pdf": "application/pdf", "png": "image/png"}`, and just call the dictionary with the given filename ending. Warning! this is not the best practice, but rather a workaround and a simple fix. Hope this helps!